# Stopping all processes with SIGTERM/heroku/discord.py bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku, discord.py

My discord.py-rewrite bot is currently being hosted on heroku. It's been fine for these past few weeks until heroku started going haywire just a few hours ago. Why is this happening?
This is the full error

```
2020-08-26T22:31:28.999683+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Relocating dyno to a new server
2020-08-26T22:31:29.006086+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to down
2020-08-26T22:31:29.008558+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from down to starting
2020-08-26T22:31:42.288485+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `python skybot.py.py`
2020-08-26T22:31:42.917236+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-08-26T22:31:51.626938+00:00 app[worker.1]: Signed In
2020-08-26T22:32:16.991403+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2020-08-26T22:32:20.126043+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-08-27T03:16:41.956314+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2020-08-27T03:16:42.134827+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 0
```

Have I ran out of hours already? Or is this just some common bug in the heroku deployment system. I never made any changes to the script btw. This just happened out of the blue.

Comment: `python skybot.py.py` Is this the right way to start your app? The double `.py` extension seems strange!

Comment: Yeah I know it seems strange but it's the only way my bot would run. I myself am not very sure why. :/ I'll try changing it